# how can I shorten my local url to just localhost?

Tags: apache, laravel, localhost, mamp, httpd.conf

I'm on a Mac, and I use MAMP to load my Laravel application.

Current URL: http://localhost:8000/

I want to change my URL to just : http://localhost/

I tried change the server name to just localhost, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

**httpd.conf**

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8000

.
.
.
.
.
ServerName localhost
```

Can someone teach me how to do this ? Is it even possible ?

Comment: The fact that `http://localhost/` is the same as `http://localhost:80/` may point you in the right direction.

Comment: But when I typed in `http://localhost/` .. nothing works.

Comment: That's because you have your Apache configured to listen on port 8000.

Comment: So what do I need to set my `Apache configured` to make it work with just only : http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

You can start the server on port 80 by doing `php artisan serve --port=80`

Comment: I got `Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: Permission denied)`

Answer (score 0):

Change `Listen 8000` to `Listen 80` in your httpd.conf